# Privilege wiki "dollar variables" refer to the wrong sites

Tags: bug, status-completed, privileges-page

The privileges page shows the names of other sites in page text.

Examples:

- [**Talk in Chat**](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/revisions/6c00b9e7-7578-42da-bd95-ecbb6c5eb36a/view-source): `the chat for $SiteName is at`

  - On [Super User](https://superuser.com/privileges/chat): «There is a link to chat in the header of every page, the chat for *Apple - Stack Exchange* is at»
  - On [Server Fault](https://serverfault.com/privileges/chat): «There is a link to chat in the header of every page, the chat for *Apple - Stack Exchange* is at»
  - On [Gaming](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/privileges/chat): «There is a link to chat in the header of every page, the chat for *Apple - Stack Exchange* is at»
- [**Participate in meta**](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/revisions/c5a439d8-87f9-4f84-8ed9-86edcf11276c/view-source): `The meta site for $SiteName is at: $MetaUrl`

  - On [Super User](https://superuser.com/privileges/participate-in-meta): «The meta site for Server Fault is at:  http://meta.serverfault.com»
  - On [Apple](https://apple.stackexchange.com/privileges/participate-in-meta): «The meta site for Server Fault is at: http://meta.serverfault.com»
  - On [Ask Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/privileges/participate-in-meta): «The meta site for Server Fault is at: http://meta.serverfault.com»

Stack Overflow renders this field correctly

Comment: Talk in Chat gives Apple to me, while Participate in Meta goes to  Server Fault :/

Comment: I'm seeing different sites - but still the wrong sites - to those mentioned here.

Comment: @Chris Weird, I can repro the same sites in incognito as well.

Comment: @badp - I'm seeing "Stack Apps" for the Talk in Chat pages and "Gaming" for the Participate in meta pages.

Comment: @Chris Can you repro that SO and SF's meta participation page behave correctly?

Comment: @badp - Participate in Meta: SO's is OK, SF is showing "Gaming". Talk in Chat: SO's is OK, SF is showing "Stack Apps".

Comment: @Chris I guess SO is the only site working correctly then :)

Comment: I get Stack Apps for Chat and GameDev for Meta. It seems very random.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Good catch,

A fix will be deployed today, suffice to say, I blame myself and caching